# Unknown bitrate error in g(mixed) opration mode in the Ieee80211DimensionalTransmitter physical layer for 2.4GHz

Tags: omnet++

In the network, there are 3 AdhocHost nodes, named hostA, hostB and hostC.
The following error occurred when the simulation is run:

> Unknown bitrate: (1.095e+07 - 1.105e+07) in operation mode: 'g(mixed)' -- in module (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211DimensionalTransmitter) WirelessA.hostA.wlan[0].radio.transmitter (id=61), during network initialization

```
*.host*.wlan[*].radio.centerFrequency = 2.412GHz
*.host*.wlan[*].radio.bandwidth = 2MHz
*.host*.wlan[*].bitrate = 11Mbps
```

Thanks, the screenshot of the error is presented in the following.
[image]

Comment: Could you edit your question and add [mcve]?

Comment: I think a reason of this error is *.host*.wlan[*].radio.bandwidth= 2MHz, probabely it must be 22MHz.

Comment: What version of INET are you using? How to reproduce your error?

Comment: I used the Inet version 4.2